# Возможно ли заполнить вектор элементами в его конструкторе с идеальной передачей?

Tags: c++, vector, конструктор, forward

Скажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли вызвать для объекта класса `std::vector` конструктор, который заполнит вектор заданным количеством элементов, каждый из которых конструируется не копированием, и не перемещением, а идеальной передачей параметров в конструктор конструируемых элементов?

Например:

```
class A
{
public:
  A(const int x, const int y) {}
};

class B
{
public:
  B(const int x, const int y)
    :
    A_{ x, y }
  {}
private:
  A A_;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<B> vec(10, 10, 10);// ?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: мне немного не понятно, поскольку для объекта класса нельзя вызвать конструктор _ он уже сконструирован

Comment: идеальная передача - это std::forward? или это просто передача, где не вызываются конструкторы копирования/перемещения?

Answer (score 3):

Нужно использовать конструктор вектора с двумя итераторами, и передать туда кастомный итератор, у которого `operator*` возвращает класс с перегруженным `operator B`.

За счет обязательного copy elision, должно получиться ноль копирований и перемещений.

Итератор должен быть random-access, чтобы вектор сразу знал сколько нужно элементов, и не перевыделял память в конструкторе.

Perfect forwarding аргументов в конструктор делать нельзя, чтобы он из них ничего не переместил.

Писал на коленке, но вроде работает:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <typename T> struct tag {};

template <typename T, typename ...P>
class ConstructingIterator
{
    std::size_t count = 0;

    struct Proxy
    {
        std::tuple<std::remove_reference_t<P> *...> params;

        operator T() const
        {
            return std::apply([](auto *... params){return T(*params...);}, params);
        }
    };
    Proxy proxy;

  public:
    using value_type = Proxy;
    using pointer = const Proxy *;
    using reference = const Proxy &;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;

    ConstructingIterator() {}
    ConstructingIterator(std::size_t count, tag<T>, P &&... params)
        : count(count), proxy{{&params...}}
    {}

    template <typename C>
    C to()
    {
        return C(*this, ConstructingIterator());
    }

    reference operator*() const
    {
        return proxy;
    }

    pointer operator->() const
    {
        return &proxy;
    }

    ConstructingIterator &operator++()
    {
        count--;
        return *this;
    }
    ConstructingIterator &operator--()
    {
        count++;
        return *this;
    }

    ConstructingIterator operator++(int)
    {
        ConstructingIterator ret;
        operator++();
        return ret;
    }
    ConstructingIterator operator--(int)
    {
        ConstructingIterator ret;
        operator--();
        return ret;
    }

    // We don't need to separately define `!=` starting from C++20.
    bool operator==(const ConstructingIterator &other) const
    {
        return count == other.count;
    }
    auto operator<=>(const ConstructingIterator &other) const
    {
        return other.count <=> count; // sic
    }

    ConstructingIterator &operator+=(difference_type d)
    {
        count -= d;
        return *this;
    }
    ConstructingIterator &operator-=(difference_type d)
    {
        count += d;
        return *this;
    }

    // We don't need to separately define `number +/- iterator` starting from C++20.
    ConstructingIterator operator+(difference_type d) const
    {
        ConstructingIterator ret(*this);
        ret += d;
        return ret;
    }
    ConstructingIterator operator-(difference_type d) const
    {
        ConstructingIterator ret(*this);
        ret -= d;
        return ret;
    }

    difference_type operator-(const ConstructingIterator &other) const
    {
        return other.count - count; // sic
    }

    reference operator[](difference_type d) const
    {
        return *(*this + d);
    }
};


struct A
{
    A() {std::cout << "A()\n";}
    A(const A &) {std::cout << "A(const A &)\n";}
    A(A &&) {std::cout << "A(A &&)\n";}
    A &operator=(const A &) {std::cout << "A &operator=(const A &)\n"; return *this;}
    A &operator=(A &&) {std::cout << "A &operator=(A &&)\n"; return *this;}
    ~A() {std::cout << "~A()\n";}

    int x = 0, y = 0;
    A(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {std::cout << "A(" << x << "," << y << ")\n";}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> vec = ConstructingIterator(3, tag<A>{}, 10, 20).to<std::vector<A>>();
    for (const A &a : vec)
        std::cout << "[" << a.x << "," << a.y << "]\n";
}
```

<kbd>[запустить на gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMS7deAB1QLC62nqGJmak3r5qdDZ2jkYubjy8SioRtAwEzMQEgcamnIrKmKr%2BaRkEUQ7OroIK6ZnZwXk1peUxcVwAlIqoBsTIHADkUgDMtsiGWADU4kM6yDXoWFTT2OIADACCw6PjmFMz6jXEmMxGy2ubkiO0YwaT0zqErsxExGcbW9c7ezoEBp7sbwuVxudxmBAAnp5MAB9AjEZiEBSAj4g3b3AxqViEcHIy7bW5omYAN0KL2RGwImCM/2ehJ%2BkK0J12ABVlhNDgZVBN0sApgB2WR8gAi01k7wpVJplO%2BEKhtCZE2ZpG5DPlRl2ADotQAFQFjZgKBQTPS0DlFUQASUp8LJ7wF5wmjvZBHQIBAvgAXjCCBM0AZ6HshRNVqLzg6nWafdriKgAB44jZO/li9ZJpPzN2/f6Ye4ZkBHIyoEnQo5UVxaPqw%2B66obYCYAKi1GrZngyJyRQxT4bTE1QUJtJEVEHavroNW7afE9sTPbTR1%2BxFoztdIGYnn%2B4Ig4gArLJt0KIMwMagG02Jq34UYFO0p9J5z0l8yIPWL%2B2mzfO1OhcrX1ePynZ35EUZ0dL9QxAiZozjcFzxjeNwM2GdPAMJwsWQEAJwMXxRAmIk2AMb0GUDSC4JxT8IKw2xeW8WxrWItBTSjUiGwQpNKJw0ty2uQkgwYmoSOgqZJAANlYp12N5fAqDLI5uNhIjpiDPNPDhKSqCrcjU3E7DeUeAdiGhFhKWAEgYMU5c3XhbRUCMaFmGQPpDWhPTnhIWFmGABCJxNSMqKtJ4XmHZMwIgny4U5NRLWtVziAgPNPW9Ud/QIZUeXuVla2VbUhNEkSz1/a8JyTEAkvoCA/XoTpYOg29apEgqmzA4UJ1q5rxS0x1KWpYRpXuWVGXVY1ASTHRuVQYcWunDq50wBclx0Z8CAQPAFGVMLiAivzosC9p/0m4DEOmzjZL6Xt%2Bxi%2Bsgr4ghJoA2d70Xar4M0pMQsOpMaPoVwzoCkgAFpliuscbog2qIKTB6lykYTPFIsTQLa96nXWzaot%2B4gcr7dG5DkCbQamwCKoIP6AZe%2B7ZofBslpW%2BGgO84GNvNYB/P0zHzpeEm8emsHpqTImcZkWmIYpx762pjs7oRg76cYxnIuZ7bByx/SBekCBaJvfHJbTFGmZZmKJnnIWnWVmLVYmsme0hw3Ztpt6RoZ1GFfRn79M5jXbqK5HHb1xWMaNy201Njm/ot7Xhbmm2bsDt6JwAejjiYAHVdnQOgwH6H07EwdAxvZTBX0pVgYMWWw0WE1YwDARTxAr51SioiYqBjIwhsFmRJFWZsIKcVB9Fds2hhFIfyuB40ffl/WXkxpbXBHa7PfBp1raJwNzNQWfiA1fmY8RpMjyIAeyRmGva1Hxjx9lp2p8HaGN4QOfR0YxfeeXkWl3v1xt%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%2BtVTyyQIr0V0uls1S5Gw3VGARLQLm9yIyWpJKoBBMxNi1lwoUYiuSqExQgEMVKHl7gtpWPaYUypOBeomJ3doGoiC5nraSJtOhB2A2KUmGgGMWU%2BhxcwCYJUG2sNnMqjNYqVmpsTRMZgGoPVnszdms9F7c1quPSKR1RauzCn6J0VgIB%2Bjbn6KQUw/RVh/tQN%2B1V7cgEKG6L0NElxOB/oIN%2BoDu1SAAGsQDcAABwagw0MbcGHO4YYAJzbm3DSoYhGhDfu4H%2BgDQHSAgf6H%2BhQIAvUIcAx%2B0gcBYAwEQFa6keB2BkAoKPfjgmUDCFEGO1YXqlGsGtMxiAThEN/qcLYDI4Jv1wdIGgIw6p6AAHlaDF2U6QLAlbRDsBM/gI4RQSTMfYxYWMhQMQDDo7RZQJmsROHhMQcEegsCafg8QPARhAudBoPQJgbAOCcF7QIcwEmxCqyEHgJwzHYBqg4FQIwKUSRuH6MJSQcHkN9hSPZv6Sc2CsDGSnWMcJt1/ShOgEQahkB/VcDGYgRo/rzEUhIcDncmMFCKBoCAlh6i5AsNoFo6jBBhD8HQCbc2fALdoDN2IVRGjDZSCUOo%2BgcjVG28UWoZQy6tE24oE7S3GgnfW20TgnRIM9D6B0SjP6aMmYY7GDDwk/rCW4L6RLEwx0ai7qsCYEBcCEFvrBtaNlPACe%2BsMAtpi5DweU8hr9/RqOkFC5h0HhHuCcD5KsbgqxcMYb5B4f9n3v1MZY6QNjSHOM8YgEgIlyEUrCZ0wjsT5gc7Q/iKQCLjAWCWbHaQAA7vCTwYW3u/ppw5hjyOJiS8IAgd1P2/sA/1DhEHYP0fscx1Rv9oXtycA1IR1YeHJDEcI/9zgkhtzCUV3Rhj9PWMY86Gh83GpOAO75IRsdHg%2BR8mEnkLHQwPtK7p4zr3b3JDR7d7HpnH7Oh5d8BobgQA)</kbd>

Comment: "конструирует новый объект" и "ноль копирований" немного противоречиво.

Comment: @KoVadim А где противоречие? Для каждого элемента нужно вызвать конструктор.

Comment: да, нужно.мне видимо нужно было немного точнее сформулировать свою мысль

Comment: Я попытался сделать Ваш пример в голове, и пока не совсем понимаю, как там избавится от ненужных автору вопроса конструкторах.

Comment: @KoVadim Сейчас попробую написать...

Comment: [Получилось.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/79ME8o) Но пока писал, понял, что если так делать, то вектор несколько раз перевыделяет память в конструкторе. Не знаю, может если доделать итератор до random-access, то этого не будет, но им нельзя возвращать из `operator*` ничего кроме ссылки, поэтому такой трюк не сработает.

Comment: Пример интересный. Сколько кода... Как бы все эти накладные расходы не превысили выгоду от отказа в копировании...

Comment: @KoVadim Кода много, но он только жонглирует указателями на параметры, по идее все должно быть быстро... Плохо что память перевыделяется, но есть у меня одна мысль.

Comment: @KoVadim Все, разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

У класса B - два параметра. А в main Вы пытаетесь туда передать три параметра. Что с этого ожидается - я не знаю. Но можно вот так

```
std::vector<B> vec{{10, 10}, {10,10} };
```

будет два объекта типа B векторе.

Но есть честный способ избавится от лишних конструкторов - emplace_back

```
std::vector<B> vec;
vec.reserve(10); // выделяем нужное кол-во памяти. Можно с запасом
vec.emplace_back(10,10); // и добавляем
vec.emplace_back(10,10);
vec.emplace_back(10,10);
vec.emplace_back(10,10);
vec.emplace_back(10,10);
```

Comment: Произойдет ли в данном случае копирование или перемещение? И как быть, если количество элементов известно только во время выполнения, или если элементов - миллионы?

Comment: будут вызваны соответствующие конструкторы, которые Вы определили. Но если Вы хотите избавится от конструкторов совсем - это никак. В приведенном Вами примере оно будет сконструировано на месте.

Comment: @MGNeo Копирование, потому что у `std::initializer_list` элементы константные.

Comment: да, со списком инициализации никак от конструктора не избавится.